# Replication in SQL Server by Merging a Publisher and Subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have 2 databases, A and B.
database A contains a subset of database B. I want to replicate any changes on database A (insert, update, delete one way replication) to database B without affecting any of database B own data.
Both databases have the same schema.

I think merge replication would be my best bet.

Be aware that SQL Server is the latest version running on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: "*database A contains a subset of database B*" - So to be clear, you're saying the same records that exist in `database A` also exist in `database B`?

Comment: Is the data flow bidirectional, or do data changes only need to flow from A to B

Comment: Merge Replication is not supported on Linux. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-replication?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @J.D. : yes, that is true.

Comment: @AMtwo: no, the flow is unidirectional from A to B only

Comment: About how many tables do you want to replicate? Do they all have primary keys defined on them?

Comment: @J.D. About 22 tables with clearly defined primary keys